# How to display an image with background-size cover in a parent div with specific percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display an image with dimensions `63x88` using `background-size: cover`. I want the image height to be a size of a percentage of the parent div. I tried it but it doesn't show the complete image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
}

.pokerf {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.middle.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}

.card {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  background-size: cover;
}

.ace.hearts {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/63x88.png?css=%7B%22border-radius%22%3A%2215px%22%7D')
}
```

```html
<div class="pokerf five">
  <div class='table'>
    <div class='tablebg'></div>
    <div class='button one'>B</div>
  
  <div class="middle flop1 card ace hearts" style='top: 50%; left: 20%;'></div>
  <div class="middle flop2 card ace hearts" style='top: 50%; left: 32%;'></div>
  <div class="middle flop3 card ace hearts" style='top: 50%; left: 44%;'></div>
  <div class="middle turn card" style='top: 50%; left: 56%;'></div>
  <div class="middle river card" style='top: 50%; left: 68%;'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want cover or percentage? you need to decide

Comment: I want the image to cover the yellow background and yellow background to be a percentage of the parent, I guess yellow background has to be ratio 63x88 somehow.

Comment: so the real question is to keep the ratio of the yellow div considering width based on height?

Comment: I can't calculate exactly because floating point errors, it displays off, how can I compensate these small errors

Answer (score 0):

Please add below css property to div having class "middle flop1 card ace hearts", it will solve your problem, and for more details visit : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[image]